# Question about xa and transaction on ejbs

Tags: websphere, ejb, jboss7.x, java-ee-6, java-ee-5

I have two question/doubt:

1. If two ejbs are deployed in different ear or different applicationserver, and one call the other, they still required XA indipendent that each one use one or more db as ?
2. if two ejbs are deployed in different server, both are annotated with trans type = required,and when teh first ejb call the second, a new transaction start or use the propagation of first ejb?

**My ejbs are deployed on Webpshere, Jboss, WebLogic and can be written with JEE 5/6/7 technology(EJB 2/3).

Thanks

Roberto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of how the EJBs are packaged (same or different EAR) or where they are deployed (same or different server), if the transaction type is `Required` (i.e. the default) then the transaction initiated by the first bean must flow to the second bean, or the call to the second bean must result in an error.

The server vendor should make no difference, as the behavior is defined in the Transactions chapter of the EJB specification. However, if the call is between vendors, then it may be more likely that transaction context propagation is not supported, in which case the call to the second bean should be rejected with an exception.

Basically, if the client (1st bean) is running in a transaction and calls to a second bean with "Required", then the transaction context must propagate to the second bean or result in an error.

Comment: 1) what do you mean about Vendor ?2)when transactin context could be not supported (an example)? Thanks

Comment: 1) Vendor is application server provider, such as Webpshere, Jboss, WebLogic, Open Liberty, etc. 2) Open Liberty would be an example of when transaction context propagation is not supported. For example, if the client is a Glassfish server, and the client begins a transaction and then calls a remote EJB on an Open Liberty server, then the transaction context will not propagate, and if the EJB method is Required, then an exception will be thrown.  If the client does not begin a transaction, then the method call would work fine, and the server would just begin a new one.

Comment: If a client attempts to propagate a transaction context, then if the EJB on the server has a transaction attribute that requires running in the context of the caller's transaction, the server must either accept the propagated transaction context or throw an exception; the server cannot just ignore it.

Comment: ok i understand, I have last Question: Use a container managed transaction of type "Supports" for second remote ejb could resolve the problem of thrown an Exceptions if not propagate? Thank you very much

Comment: No, `Supports` would not avoid the exception. `Supports` indicates the EJB must run under the caller's transaction if it exists. So, if the caller does have an active transaction, then the EJB must run under that transaction or throw an exception indicating that it cannot. Basically, if the behavior cannot be identical to when transaction propagation is supported, then an exception must be thrown.